# Deploying an EJB .jar to jBoss/WildFly from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I am new to Java EE. I use Eclipse, jBoss/WildFly and Maven. I have a multi module Maven project:

- parent Maven project (`pom`)

  - web application (`war`)
  - EJB project (`jar`)

Currently, the EJB `jar` project is packaged inside the web application and the entire solution is deployed as one `war` file.

I want to change it: I need to deploy the `war` and the `jar` projects to the application server independently (as two independent applications). Then the web project could access the EJBs via their remote interfaces.

The problem:

I can deploy the `war` project in Eclipse with the `Run As` > `Run On Server` context menu, however when I attempt to deploy the `jar` project in the same way, I get an error message saying that the project cannot be deployed.

How can I deploy my projects independently from Eclipse?

Should I wrap the `jar` project into an `ear` project? If so, can I convert my `jar` project into an `ear` project, or do I have to keep my `jar` project and create one more project to wrap it into an `ear`? (I would no like to introduce one more project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your packaging for your EJB project.  You should have

> `<packaging>ejb</packaging>`

This will allow you to run the EJB project on the server.